# How to change CacheStorage key for dll caching?

Tags: c#, caching, blazor, webassembly

I am currently working on developing a Blazor WASM application that is a framework for a form builder which executes on a web forms application. The issue I've been experiencing is that the caching of the dll's on chrome all appear to have specific keys that target the current url. These cached dlls share the same hash however we use the URLS for encoding data, they are slightly different depending on which user you select. When you select the same user the cached dll's load just fine.

All examples regarding the Cache Storage of Blazor WASM dll's share the same 'blazor-resources~/~' key however ours are being structured [however ours are being structured like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12nEM.png)

so every new page the users enters will not used the already cached framework and instead create a new cache and key for it.